# Appengine - querying database right after putting something in

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In one place of code I do something like this:

```
FormModel(.. some data here..).put()
```

And a couple lines below I select from the database:

```
FormModel.all().filter(..).fetch(100)
```

The problem I noticed - sometimes the fetch doesn't notice the data I just added.

My theory is that this happens because I'm using high replication storage, and I don't give it enough time to replicate the data. But how can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the data is in the same entity group there is no way to guarantee that the data will be the most up to data (If I [understand this section](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview.html#Understanding_Datastore_Writes) correctly).

Comment: Thanks. This seems like the reason.

Comment: I'll keep the question open for a day in case someone provides some way to wait for apply / force apply..

Comment: @Merlin, Yes keep it open, this a very impotent question and I myself have project that I don't want to migrate to HRD unless there is some sort of solution for this.

Comment: Your answer states the opposite of what is the case - strong consistency is only available inside an entity group, not across them - and this only applies if you use an ancestor filter in your entity group.

Comment: @NickJohnson Why the is my answer the opposite? I said it needs to be in the same entity group

Comment: "Unless the data is not in the same entity group" - I don't think you intended a double negative there.

Answer (score 2):

Shay is right: there's no way to know when the datastore will be ready to return the data you just entered.

However, you *are* guaranteed that the data will be entered *eventually,* once the call to `put` completes successfully.  That's a lot of information, and you can use it to work around this problem.  When you get the data back from `fetch`, just append/insert the new entities that you know will be in there eventually!  In most cases it will be good enough to do this on a per-request basis, I think, but you could do something more powerful that uses memcache to cover all requests (except cases where memcache fails).

The hard part, of course, is figuring out when you should append/insert which entities. It's obnoxious to have to do this workaround, but a relatively low price to pay for something as astonishingly complex as the HRD.

Comment: yeah, this is my "Plan B" - i'd prefer a more streamlined solution :)

Comment: I think this is the best solution that exists right now.  I can imagine a library that automatically scans recently `put` entities for inclusion in query and get results, but I haven't heard of it.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions#Java_Isolation_and_consistency

> This consistent snapshot view also extends to reads after writes
>   inside transactions. Unlike with most databases, queries and gets
>   inside a Datastore transaction do not see the results of previous
>   writes inside that transaction. **Specifically, if an entity is modified
>   or deleted within a transaction, a query or get returns the original
>   version of the entity as of the beginning of the transaction, or
>   nothing if the entity did not exist then.**